# How to show in a UILabel what you Selected in a UITableViewCell (didSelectedRowAtIndexPath)

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I am coding a registration form where users must enter their country. I listed the countries through a .plist file in a UITableView (Classe ViewController). In addition , I set the single selection with the checkmark. After selected the country the APP must go back and show in the country label the selected row (like a normal reg form).

Here whats under    didSelectRowAtIndePath:

```
   -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

// Uncheck the previous checked row
if(self.checkedIndexPath)
{
    UITableViewCell* uncheckCell = [tableView
                                    cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.checkedIndexPath];
    uncheckCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
if([self.checkedIndexPath isEqual:indexPath])
{
    self.checkedIndexPath = nil;
}
else
{
    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    self.checkedIndexPath = indexPath;
}
```

Thanks for helping me.

Richard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have your label and your table in the same controller you can do this:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    [self.yourLabel setText:[self.arrayCountries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

}
```

but if you have your table and your label in differents controllers you can use NSUserDefaults for keep your selection like this:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:[self.arrayCountries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] forKey:@"selectedCountry"];

}
```

and in your controller where you have your label get this selection

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.labelCountry setText:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"selectedCountry"]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add that line like this

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

 country.text=uncheckCell.label.text;//add this wherever you want, but it should be in this method only 
}
```

where country is the label you created.
Also this line of code will work only if your label that is country and your table where you select the row both are in the same class,could you mention how you have made your classes like where your `UITableView` is?and where your `UILabel` is?

Comment: is it ok define the label in the ViewController.h:    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *country; and then call it how u wrote there?

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you should use `delegates`. Once the country selected, call a delegate function in previous form and set the value of cell text.

e.g., (untested code to give an idea)

```
if(self.checkedIndexPath)
{
    UITableViewCell* uncheckCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.checkedIndexPath];
    uncheckCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}

if([self.checkedIndexPath isEqual:indexPath])
{
    self.checkedIndexPath = nil;
}
else
{
    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    self.checkedIndexPath = indexPath;

    // Trigger previous form to get the current form's data
    // Here self.delegate takes address of previous form
    [self.delegate setThisCountryNameToOwnerFormWithText:cell.titleLabel.text];
    // Probably go back like this
    // [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```